# Time x axis does not catch data from service (Angular, SignalR)

Tags: angular, chart.js, signalr

The service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import { resolve } from 'dns';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ChartDataPm1200 } from '../_models/chartmodel';

export interface ChartData{
  data: number,
  time: number
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SpeedService {
  baseUrl = 'https://localhost:7068/';
  data: ChartDataPm1200[];
  datachart: ChartDataPm1200;
  resulttime: string;
  finaltime : any;
  result:any;

  private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection;

  public StartConnection = () =>{
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
    .withUrl("https://localhost:7068/charts", {
      skipNegotiation: true,
      transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
    })
    .build();
    this.hubConnection.start().then(()=>console.log('Connection started')).catch(err => console.log('Error while connecting: '+err));
  }

  public addTransferChartDataListener = () => {
    this.hubConnection.on('transferchartdataPm1200', (data) => {
      this.data= data;
      console.log(data);
    });
}

public addTransferTime = async() => {
  this.hubConnection.on('transfertime',(data) => {
    this.resulttime =  JSON.stringify(data).replaceAll('{"time":','');
    this.finaltime = this.resulttime.replaceAll('}','');
    console.log(this.finaltime);
})
return this.finaltime;
}



}
```

I have the HTML of the line chart set up like this:

`

```
<h1>{{signalRService.finaltime}}</h1> <!-- for testing purpose --> 
        <div style="display: block;">
    <canvas baseChart width= "400px" height= "200px"
            [data]="linechartdata"
            [options]="linechartOptions"
            [legend]="linechartLegend"
            [type]="'line'">
          </canvas>
  </div>
```

And the signalRService works well as I get the result like this:
[image]

However, in the component, I set up `signalRService.finaltime` for the source of the x axis (time axis) like this
`

```
export class LineSpeedChartComponent implements OnInit {
    public linechartdata:ChartData = {
      datasets: [{
        label:"Ampere",
        data: [{x:+this.signalRService.finaltime,y:12}]
    }]
    };  

    public linechartOptions: ChartOptions = {
     
      responsive: true,
      scales: {
        x: { 
          type: 'time',
          min: Date.now() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
          max: Date.now() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
          ticks: {
            source: 'auto',
          },
          time:{
            unit: 'hour', //second
            displayFormats:{
              hour: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" //second = 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'
            },
            tooltipFormat: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
          },
          adapters: { 
            date: {
              locale: vi, 
            },
        },
      },
        y: {
            min: 0,

        },
      }
  };
```

And no data is showed in the chart, including the data of the y axis. But if I replace `this.signalRService.finaltime` with a specific value, it works fine.

Please send help !!!